# Baby Rudin 1.37—Proof of $|\mathbf x \cdot \mathbf y|\le|\mathbf x||\mathbf y|$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality, vector-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In Baby Rudin Theorem 1.35, he proves the *Schwarz inequality* for complex numbers:

> If $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $b_1,\dots,b_n$ are complex numbers, then
> $$
> \left|\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_j\overline{b_j}\right|^2\le\sum_{j=0}^{n}|a_j|^2\sum_{j=0}^{n}|b_j|^2
> $$

Then, in Theorem 1.37, he states the *Schwarz inequality* for euclidean $k$-spaces:

> Suppose $x,y\in\Bbb{R}^k$. Then,
> $$
> |\mathbf x \cdot \mathbf y|\le|\mathbf x||\mathbf y|
> $$

He states that this theorem is an "immediate consequence of the Schwarz inequality" for complex numbers. I don't see how this follows: Theorem 1.35 applies to $\Bbb{C}$, not $\Bbb{R}^k$. What am I missing?

Comment: if 1.35 applies for complex numbers, it certainly applies for real numbers

Comment: Perhaps the correct comparison is to say that 1.35 applies  to $\mathbb C^k$, not $\mathbb C$

Comment: Real numbers can be taken to be complex numbers with a $0$ imaginary part, and $y_i =\overline {y_i}$ if $y_i$ is real

Comment: The standard inner product involves a sum of product of real (and hence complex) numbers.

Comment: @CalvinKhor: I think I see what you mean. Since $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $\mathbf{b}=(b_1,\dots,b_n)$, we have $a,b\in\Bbb{C}^n$. Is that right?

Comment: @Joe yup yup 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying 1.35 with  $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $b_1,\dots,b_n$ being real numbers (which are included in complex numbers), we get
$$
\left|\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_j {b_j}\right|^2\le\sum_{j=0}^{n}|a_j|^2\sum_{j=0}^{n}|b_j|^2
.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Let $\mathbf x=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $\mathbf y=(b_1,\dots,b_n)$. The inequality
$$
\left|\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_j {b_j}\right|^2\le\sum_{j=0}^{n}|a_j|^2\sum_{j=0}^{n}|b_j|^2
$$
can be rewritten as
$$
|\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y}|^2\le|\mathbf{x}|^2|\mathbf{y}|^2 \, ,
$$
and taking square roots yields the desired result. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct, @Joe.  Note that all the quantities are non-negative

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this inequality even apply to $\Bbb{C}^k$? And if so, can it be proven just from Theorem 1.35, or is more work needed?

Comment: Yes, from Theorem 1.35

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Since $\mathbf{x}=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $\mathbf{y}=(b_1,\dots,b_n)$, we have $x,y\in\Bbb{C}^n$. Is that right?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathbf x=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $\mathbf y=(b_1,\ldots, b_n)$ with the $a_i$ and $b_i$ real, then $\overline{b_i}=b_i$ and we have $$|\mathbf x\cdot\mathbf y|^2=\left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\right|^2=\left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\overline{b_i}\right|^2\le \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^2\sum_{i=1}^n |b_i|^2=|\mathbf x|^2|\mathbf y|^2.$$

Comment: I think you are missing a square root in the last 2 relations in the above string

Comment: Yes. Fixed it. Thanks.